# lucene score a given document (e.g., docid)

Tags: lucene, search-engine

Maybe it is a simple question... I want to know how to use lucene to score a given document (e.g. docid) instead of performing search, since I know which document to score.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an [`Explanation`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Explanation.html) would be a likely approach.  It's `getValue()` will return the score:

```
Explanation explain = indexSearcher.explain(myQuery, docNo);
float theScore = explain.getValue();
```

(You can also get a lot of other information about how that score was calculated from `Explanation.toString()`)

Comment: Hi there, great thanks. The way you suggested does work. BTW, computing an explanation is as expensive as executing the query over the entire index.